# ArcGIS Survey 123 connect : Filling a field in a 1st form from a field in a 2nd form

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-online, arcgis-survey123, arcgis-survey123-connect

I created a 1st form where I resigned the name of an observation "NAME OBSERVATION".
I created a 2nd form with a "NAME OBSERVATION" field.
I want to automatically fill in the "NAME OBSERVATION" field of the 2nd form from the "NAME OBSERVATION" field of the 1st form.
How can I do this?

More information :

- My forms are stored on ArcGIS Online.
- I use my phone to collect data in the field. Probably, there is no internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your workflow, this can be done using URL parameters. Use a calculation to generate a URL with parameters, then use the URL to open the other survey with prefilled values.

For more info, see:

- [Survey123 Tricks of the Trade: Web form URL parameters](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-survey123-blog/survey123-tricks-of-the-trade-web-form-url/ba-p/894722)
- [Integrate with other apps](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/survey123/reference/integratewithotherapps.htm)